# FCM - How to get icon to be valid?

Tags: android, firebase, android-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am sending a Firebase Cloud Messaging notification to my Android app, but the icon on the notification is not showing correctly. its on nexus I'm having the trouble (KitKat).

and im using the following sdk:

```
 minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 24
```

The image (.png) is a logo I am pulling from the drawable folder and it looks like this:

[image]

But now when I use it in my notification it looks like this:

[image]

Keep in mind I am sending the notification using an API call like this:

```
https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
```

and the post body looks like this:

```
    { "notification": {
    "title": "Your Title",
    "text": "Your Text",
     "click_action": "OPEN_ACTIVITY_1"
  },
    "data": {
    "keyname": "some data item name "
    },
  "to":"eZm-5IM8dkE:APA91bFkC9kZSgZblDr_4JBB-MNOCkITsRGSECykFzXQE70zzM8rShP66pPYIX4iBio3V9sN1Go1q4o6dGhybm6SPRio3asC-6NIltzQfc0ZlmWrexxxxxxxxxxxxxxxiHygCx2y"
}
```

I noticed I am not setting the icon anywhere, but I don't think that's the issue. Notice how its a parallelogram in both images, so I think its just processing it differently. What am I doing wrong?

also note in the Android Manifest, I have set the following:

```
<meta-data           android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
        android:resource="@drawable/mylogo" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FCM is showing your icon correctly but **Android (not FCM) is changing the icon color to white.**

This is the standard behavior of Android and is documented here:
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0-changes.html#BehaviorNotifications
(see the last paragraph under Notifications > Material design style)

Comment: Is this all versions of android now?  I'm targetting api 19

Comment: are you using targetSdkVersion = 19 in your gradle.build / AndroidManifest ?

Comment: minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 24
         .    my fault. so my target is 24 but my minimum is 19.

Comment: I see what your saying. So i can change the background color (accent color) but the icon will always be white, right ?  Do you know if this is the same right up to nougat ?

Comment: Every android version has a slightly different notification style. In N actually the icon is colored with the accent color and doesn't have any background.